# Tcl - Differentiate between list/dict and anonymous proc

Tags: tcl

I wrote the following proc, which simulates the filter function in Lodash (javascript library) (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter). You can call it in 3.5 basic formats, seen in the examples section. For the latter three calling options I would like to get rid of the the requirement to send in -s (shorthand). In order to do that I need to differentiate between an anonymous proc and a list/dict/string.

I tried looking at `string is`, but there isn't a string is proc. In researching here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/10166 I found they recommend `info complete`, however in most cases the parameters would pass that test regardless of the type of parameter.

Does anyone know of a way to reliable test this? I know I could leave it or change the proc definition, but I'm trying to stay as true as possible to Lodash.

Examples:

```
set users [list \
          [dict create user barney age 36 active true] \
          [dict create user fred age 40 active false] \
        ]

 1. set result [_filter [list 1 2 3 4] {x {return true}}]
 2. set result [_filter $users -s [dict create age 36 active true]]
 3. set result [_filter $users -s [list age 36]]
 4. set result [_filter $users -s "active"]
```

Proc Code:

```
proc _filter {collection predicate args} {

# They want to use shorthand syntax
if {$predicate=="-s"} {

    # They passed a list/dict
    if {[_dictIs {*}$args]} {
        set predicate {x {
            upvar args args
            set truthy 1
            dict for {k v} {*}$args {
                if {[dict get $x $k]!=$v} {
                    set truthy false
                    break
                }
            }
            return $truthy
        }}

    # They passed just an individual string
    } else {
        set predicate {x {
            upvar args args;
            if {[dict get $x $args]} {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }}
    }
}

# Start the result list and the index (which may not be used)
set result {}
set i -1

# For each item in collection apply the iteratee.
# Dynamically pass the correct parameters.
set paramLen [llength [lindex $predicate 0]]
foreach item $collection {
    set param [list $item]
    if {$paramLen>=2} {lappend param [incr i];}
    if {$paramLen>=3} {lappend param $collection;}
    if {[apply $predicate {*}$param]} {
        lappend result $item
    }
}
return $result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is `x {return true}` a string, a list, a dictionary or a lambda term (the correct name for an anonymous proc)?

The truth is that it may be *all* of them; it would be correct to say it was a value that was a member of any of the mentioned types. You need to describe your intent more precisely and explicitly rather than hiding it inside some sort of type magic. That greater precision may be achieved by using an option like `-s` or by different main command names, but it is still necessary either way. You cannot correctly and safely do what you seek to do.

---

**In a little more depth…**

All Tcl values are valid as strings.

Lists have a defined syntax and are properly subtypes of strings. (They're implemented differently internally, but you are supposed to ignore such details.)

Dictionaries have a syntax that is equivalent to lists with even numbers of elements where the elements at the even indices are all unique from each other.

Lambda terms are lists with two or three elements (the third element is the name of the context namespace, and defaults to the global namespace if it is absent). The first element of the list needs to be a valid list as well.

A two-element list matches the requirements for all the above. In Tcl's actual type logic, it is simultaneously *all* of the above. A particular instantiation of the value might have a particular implementation representation under the covers, but that is a transient thing that does not reflect the true type of the value.

Tcl's type system is different to that of many other languages.

Comment: Right, I was wondering if anyone had a clever way of saying a lambda term has this, but a list/dict/string doesn't. The only potential difference I see is that a lambda len=2 or 3. if it was 3 I could assume lambda, since I really only accept dict or string. But if its len=2 the only thing I could think of is to look at the first component (args), and check if its was more than 1, if so, its most likely a lambda or a dict key that has spaces. Ultimately, I came to the same conclusion but wanted to see if someone was more clever...